# WPF TabItem Header Styling

Tags: wpf, xaml, header, styles, tabcontrol

I'm trying to style a TabControl and have got 75% of the way there, but I'm having difficulty styling the actual TabItems:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is remove the default ContentPresenter so that I can make the tab items partially transparent with rounded edges instead of the place holder red and green i have now.

I'm sure it's probably not that difficult, but I just can't figure it out so any help would be most appreciated!

Here's the XAML for the TabControl so far:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#41020202">
  <TabControl.BitmapEffect>
    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Color="Black" Direction="270"/>
  </TabControl.BitmapEffect>  
  <TabControl.Resources>    
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>      
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />      
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">        
        <Setter.Value>          
          <DataTemplate>        
            <Border x:Name="grid" Background="Red">
              <ContentPresenter>
                <ContentPresenter.Content>
                  <TextBlock Margin="4" FontSize="15" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </ContentPresenter.Content>             
                <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>                
                  <RotateTransform Angle="270" />              
                </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>            
              </ContentPresenter>  
            </Border>        
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
              </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
          </DataTemplate>        
        </Setter.Value>      
      </Setter>    
    </Style>  
  </TabControl.Resources>
  <TabControl.Background>
    <RadialGradientBrush Center="-0.047,0.553" GradientOrigin="-0.047,0.553" RadiusY="1.231" RadiusX="0.8">
      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#06FFFFFF"/>
      <GradientStop Color="#14FFFFFF"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
  </TabControl.Background>  
  <TabItem Header="Tab Item 1" />  
  <TabItem Header="Tab Item 2" />  
  <TabItem Header="Tab Item 3" />  
  <TabItem Header="Tab Item 4" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: The content presenter is what shows the Text in the tabs. Do you mean you want to remove the gray background?

Comment: Yep! If I remove the grid background, I get the default gray tab style which I want to replace with a nicer partially transparent and rounded corner border

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this style instead, it modifies the template itself. In there you can change everything you need to transparent:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Grid>
          <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent"
                  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="5">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True">
              <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
          </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
        </ContentPresenter>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkRed" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped! Quick question though, how would i change the font properties (size and color mainly)?

Thanks again

Comment: NM - I changed the TextBlock.Font... property in the content presenter tag and all's well!

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a border property? The border has a "CornerRadius" property that you can modify.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

While searching for a way to round tabs, I found Carlo's answer and it did help but I needed a bit more.  Here is what I put together, based on his work.  This was done with MS Visual Studio 2015.

The Code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MealNinja"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Rounded Tabs Example" Height="550" Width="700" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" FontFamily="DokChampa" FontSize="13.333" ResizeMode="CanMinimize" BorderThickness="0">
    <Window.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Window.Effect>
    <Grid Background="#FF423C3C">
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" TabStripPlacement="Left" Margin="6,10,10,10" BorderThickness="3">
            <TabControl.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border Name="Border" Background="#FF6E6C67" Margin="2,2,-8,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="10">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" ContentSource="Header" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,12,2" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <Rectangle Height="100" Width="10" Margin="0,0,-10,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="#FFD4D0C8"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="ContentSite" Property="Width" Value="30" />
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFD4D0C8" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF6E6C67" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                    </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6E6C67" />
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="90" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="DokChampa" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                    <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="False" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="tabGrids">
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="#FFE5E5E5" />
                    <Setter Property="Grid.Margin" Value="6,10,10,10" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Resources>
            <TabItem Header="Planner">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource tabGrids}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Section 2">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource tabGrids}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Section III">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource tabGrids}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Section 04">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource tabGrids}"/>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tools">
                <Grid Style="{StaticResource tabGrids}"/>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Nice one, I like that the selected tab is a bit bigger then the others. How to do the same for a vertical TabControl? I tried, but if I modify ContentSite (using Height) all tabs get bigger, but I want only the selected one to be bigger...