# Create a Style for TabItem in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to show an image and Text on each and every tabItem of my TabControl.

So, I created a Style as follows:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Header">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="#FF2A2A2A" Margin="-7,-2" Cursor="Hand">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Tag}" Margin="10"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="32"  Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,10,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

Now in the TabItem:

```
<TabItem Tag="Images/Plus.png" Content="Create New" />
```

But I don't see any header on any tabItems??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RelativeSource` to travel up Visual tree to get your property bindings to work. `By default it will search for property in DataContext of Image and not on TabItem`.

```
<Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                             AncestorType=TabItem}}" Margin="10"/>
```

and similarly for `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"
           FontSize="32"  Foreground="White" Margin="0,10,10,10"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify the name of the style

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Style.Setters>
```

and indicate style in TabItem

```
<TabItem Tag="Images/Plus.png" Content="Create New" Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" />
```

Comment: I have used that after having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506568/wpf-tabitem-header-styling
. Following the above link I have got Text But still I am not getting any image.

Comment: Try <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" instead of {Binding Tag}.
But I'm not shure