# XamlParse Exception when Applying Style

Tags: wpf

This is a first project using WPF and Styles.
Development tool is VS2010.

I have the following style definitions:

```
<!-- Base Style Setting-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="TabControlBase">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Width"  Value="Auto" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemBase">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>

<!-- Sub Style Setting-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="LTabEquipment" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Height="36" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/gears.png" Width="36" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="Equipment" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="LTabHistory" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Height="36" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/history.png" Width="36" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="History" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="HTabDBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="14" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/dbase.png" Width="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="stretch" VerticalAlignment="stretch" />
                <TextBlock Text="grid view" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</Style>
```

Then in my MainWindow.xaml includes:

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="2" Name="tabLeft" TabStripPlacement="Left">
        <TabItem x:Name="tabLeftEquipment" Style="{StaticResource LTabEquipment}">
            <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlBase}" Name="tabTopEquipment" >
                <TabItem x:Name="tabTopEquipmentGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase}">
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="tabLeftHistory" Style="{StaticResource LTabHistory}">
            <TabControl Height="Auto" Name="tabTopHistory" Width="Auto">
                <TabItem x:Name="tabTopHistoryGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase}" >
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
```

At design time the styles provide the appearance I want, but at runtime I get an exception:

'Set property 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style' threw an exception.'

Which points to line:

```
                <TabItem x:Name="tabTopEquipmentGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase}">
```

Please help with finding the cause of the exception...Thanks!

---

I found the following in details, but still can't figure which element is causing the problem to correct.

```
   Message=Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.
```

Comment: Are you sure the image source path is correct at runtime?

Comment: Best clue I have so far is that it has to do with <Setter Property="Header"> or that the HTabDBase is being applied in multiple locations.

Comment: @ashur668 I have used your code as is, and it works perfectly. I defined all styles in `Window.Resources`. And you must be doing something else in your code.

Comment: Agreed, I over simplified my original entry.  The problem appears to mainfest when the HTabDBase style is used in more than one TabItem.

Comment: I revised the code sample above from MainWindow.xaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by using `x:Shared="False"` in your styles containing the `Images`. By default, all resources have `x:Shared="True"` which means WPF creates only a single instance of each resource. So when any object requests the resource using `StaticResource` or whatever, that instance is returned instead of creating a new instance. This causes a problem in your case because here:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabTopEquipmentGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase}">
</TabItem>
```

the style puts an instance of an image inside the header. Therefore the `Image` becomes a child of the `TabItem`. Now here:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabTopHistoryGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase}" >
</TabItem>
```

you set the style again, which means you put the same instance of the image inside the tabItem's visual tree. But the image already has a parent => The exception is thrown because `UIElements` can have only one parent..

Styles are not meant to set the Content of controls. Styles are supposed to change it's properties. But `x:Shared=False` fixes it :)

Another, and more elegant way is set the `HeaderTemplate` instead of the `Header`. Since styles are supposed to change the properties, it can change the content template right? Yes it can. (Note `ContentTemplate` not `Template` which is the template of the control itself. This was what you set in your answers. You are supposed to set the ContentTemplate instead if you only want to "style" the content.) Example:

```
<Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Height="36" Width="36" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="History" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

So you don't need `x:Shared` anymore. `Template`s do not suffer the same problem because it is not shared. A new instance of the template is created for each element.

Comment: Fantastic!  Using the HeaderTemplate worked great and you explaination ofx:Shared was excellent too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't grasp the solution first time I read it, but found the final clue in:

[WPF TabItem Header Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506568/wpf-tabitem-header-styling)

Using the Template property and ControlTemplate, instead of applying the style to the Header property, prevented the problem.

***Revised Style Code***

```
<!-- Base Style Setting-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}" x:Key="TabControlBase">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Width"  Value="Auto" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemBase">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="VTabImage">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="36" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0" />
</Style>

<!-- Sub Style Setting-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="LTabEquipment" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Height="36" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/gears.png" Width="36" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Equipment" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="LTabHistory" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Image Height="36" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/history.png" Width="36" Margin="0,5,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="History" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>                    
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="HTabDBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">  
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="14" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/dbase.png" Width="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="stretch" VerticalAlignment="stretch" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Grid View" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</Style>
```

**This however is not an ideal solution;**
as using ControlTemplate removes all default style and operation of the original control.

Still looking for better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to not trigger the exception, but not fond of this either.

The exception seems to occur when HTabDBase style is applied to more than one TabItem within the application.

To prove this I copy/paste two copies and changed their keys to HTabDBase1 and HTabDBase2. I then applied each separately. Other than the key, the style definition is identical.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="HTabDBase2" BasedOn="{StaticResource TabItemBase}">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Height="14" Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/dbase.png" Width="14" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="stretch" VerticalAlignment="stretch" />
                <TextBlock Text="grid view" Margin="2,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="2" Name="tabLeft" TabStripPlacement="Left">
    <TabItem x:Name="tabLeftEquipment" Style="{StaticResource LTabEquipment}">
        <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlBase}" Name="tabTopEquipment" >
            <TabItem x:Name="tabTopEquipmentGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase1}">
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabLeftHistory" Style="{StaticResource LTabHistory}">
        <TabControl Height="Auto" Name="tabTopHistory" Width="Auto">
            <TabItem x:Name="tabTopHistoryGridView" Style="{StaticResource HTabDBase2}" >
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </TabItem>
```

**But this solution seems to defeat much of the purpose of creating the style to begin with;**
i.e. I create the style to be able to reuse it in any location, but using it in more than one location causes a run time error.